# How to fetch json object dynamically in angular 4

Tags: angular

### Here is my Json, I will try to fetch Set1 and Set2 dynamically

```
{
  "ForumDetails":
    [{
      "SetNames":
          [
            {
             "Set1":[{
                     "UseName": "David",
                     "MobileNumber": "815642147"
                     }]
            },
            {
             "Set2":[{
                       "UseName": "David",
                        "MobileNumber": "815642147"
                    }]
            }
         ] 
    }]
}
```

### Here is my html code currently am fetching manually, but i want Set1 and its key:value dynamically

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of ForumDetails">
   <table *ngFor="let value of item['SetNames']">
      <tr *ngFor="let set of value.Set1">
      <td>   {{set.UserName}} <td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [http.get (url)](https://angular.io/guide/http)

If you're looking for an example, you can checkout my [basic web](http://muftiahmadsaeedi.com) (which fetches list of videos from youtube channel, and uses json response just like yours) with source code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
```

```
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white" width="330" height="190">
    <img class="card-img-top" [src]="item" (click)="loadVideo(i)" width="320" height="180" />
  </div>

</div>
```

.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

variable1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
autoplay = '?autoplay=1';

videos = [];
thumbnails = [];
titles = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

}

transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

ngOnInit() {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search' +
        '?key=AIzaSyCXNofX9tlp5FKqWOw6cHrIOhYPAlsZOdw&channelId=UCRUcBt1POKGAe8Og1PQIZig&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20';
    this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(r => {
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
            console.log(r);
            // const json = JSON.parse(r.toString());
            // this.videos = this.videos.items[0].id.videoId;

            const items = r['items'];
            if (items != null) {
                for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    this.videos[i] = this.variable1 + items[i].id.videoId + this.autoplay;
                    this.thumbnails[i] = this.transform(items[i].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url);
                    this.titles[i] = items[i].snippet.title;
                }
            }
            console.log('************************');
            console.log(this.videos);
            // this.videos = r['items'];
        });
}

loadVideo(index) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('video-thumbnail-container')[index].innerHTML = '<iframe width="330" height="175" src=' + this.videos[0] + '  frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen (click)="loadVideo($arg)"></iframe>';
    console.log(index);
    console.log('******');
}
```

}